# How to add a new field in aggregation in projection with blank value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my code.

```
db.article.aggregate(
{ $project : {
    title : 1 ,
    stats : {
        pv : "$name",
        foo : "$foo",
        dpv : 1
    }
}}
);
```

In that name,foo are there in collection.
That dpv is not, but i need to add that one.

**OUTPUT CAME**

```
{
PV:"shan",
foo:"sd"
}
```

I need that dpv also in the ouput with null value.

Is it possible ?
How to achieve this ?
I am new to mongoDb.
(using node.js)

Comment: Why not just add the value in your Node.js code as it iterates through the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `fieldname:1` means "pass through this field as is.

You want to have a literal `1` value - the simplest way is to create an expression that will return 1.  I suggest:  `dpv:{$add:[1]}`

Answer (score 3):

Asya is correct in that you need to specify a literal `1`, and while the solution works a more correct solution would be:

`dpv: {$literal: 1}`